# Manipulating lists through findall in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a little trouble manipulating lists using findall() method

My knowledge base is just this: no/3 --> no(User_Id,_,Tags)

In this moment i have the combination tags part done that i will explain next

In this moment the problem is the get the users that have these sets of tags (combination tags), and next choose the largest one that have at least N elements/users

```
For example if the groups are:  
t1,t2,t3,t4 --> uA,uB,uC  
t1,t2,t3,t5 --> uA,uD  
t1,t2,t3,t6 --> uA,uB,uD,uE  
t1,t2,t4,t5 --> uA,uC,uE  
t1,t2,t4,t6 --> uA   
t1,t2,t5,t6 --> uA,uE
```

If N is equal to or less than 4 then it will be the group of users uA,uB,uD,uE for tags t1,t2,t3,t6 (In the end this should be showed/write)
if N were 5 or more, no result appers

Thats it, sry if my grammar its not good and any answer/question is welcome :)

Comment: if you could somehow devise a minimal example...

Comment: I think i give an example in the words "In other words" even the words "no group would result", using the user "uA"

Comment: I have tried to answer, but I do not understand. Mandatory_tags makes sense, the users must have `t2` and `t4` in common. The other part, you say "*a minimum number of users to be obtained*", then you say "*the largest group with 4 common tags*", then you say "*the largest group as long as it has at least N elements*". So is the new number the number of users, the maximum number of common tags or minimum number of users returned? Are there two new numbers needed, MaxNumCommonTags and MinNumUsers ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler sry if you dont understand because im bad at english :c but let see if this sentence make sense for you. The objective is suggested the largest group for a given (known) user as long as you have a minimum of N users and common T tags, for  the example i gave for user uA , if the N is 4 or more than 4, should return uA,uB,uD,uE , if N is 3 uA,uB,uC or 2 solution uA,uC,uE. Briefly, the "group" will be a set of users with the combination tags "t1,t2,t3,t6 --> uA,uB,uD,uE"

Comment: short specific focused question with minimal code is much more likely to get an answer.